# Static Bootstrap Navbar creates white space above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have problems with my bootstrap navbar. I changed it from a navbar-fixed to a navbar-static, and a blank white space is created right as I changed it. Is there any idea on how to fix it?
Here is my navbar.css

```
    .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 15px 40px 10px 40px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

.navbar-brand img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #757575;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    background-color: transparent !IMPORTANT;
}

.navbar-default li.active a {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #202020;
    color: #202020 !IMPORTANT;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #202020 !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Along with the html,
http://pastebin.com/21pW6ixt

[image]

Comment: Also post the html code

Comment: @zaingz updated

Answer (score 2):

The above answers may be old answers for earlier versions,but for Bootstrap 4, after trying some of the above, I realized that I just needed to include fixed-top to the class to remove the white space above the nav-bar.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary ">
```

With out fixed-top - white space, that stays around even if you change the padding manually

With fixed-top the nav-bar at the top as expected....

It is in the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement
and notes 
"Fixed navbars use position: fixed, meaning they’re pulled from the normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., padding-top on the )"

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have float right applied to class navbar-right. Remove the right float and all the nav items will come float left again by default.

Edit your css to remove the float right declaration (I've commented it out to show you what to remove):

```css
.navbar-right {
    /* float: right !important; */
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Comment: That is not my problem. My problem is that when I made it a static navbar, it added the blank white space above it. The navbar is transparent.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I can't see that in the code you posted. Can you post a proper js fiddle with all your code here so i can have a better look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to change the padding on `.navbar-default` element by setting the `padding-top` to zero (it will up the element of the navbar):

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0px 40px 10px 40px;
}
```

and remove the `margin-bottom` from the `.navbar` element (it will remove the blank zone under these elements):

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

(based on what i could reproduce from your two snippets)
Before and after :
[image]
[image]

Comment: It did not seem to work. It just moved the logo and the nav items up.

Comment: @L.Wu I edited my answer but maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve

Comment: This is what I want it to look like: http://i.imgur.com/bGy3Gzm.jpg (with navbar-fixed-top) but I want to use navbar-static-top. When I use navbar-static-top, it adds the white space on top of the navbar